# Data Extraction from a .seg file

Tags: linux, bash, shell, speech-recognition

I have a .seg file which holds data of clusters formed after diarization of an audio file.
The file has the following data:

```
;; cluster S0 [ score:FS = -32.694324625945725 ] [ score:FT = 
-33.32942628147711 ] [ score:MS = -32.847416329096404 ] [ score:MT = 
-33.45196981196905 ] 
ElonN 1 0 758 F S U S0
;; cluster S1 [ score:FS = -33.14490351155562 ] [ score:FT = 
-33.420111126893076 ] [ score:MS = -32.29039025858266 ] [ score:MT = 
-32.85038927851203 ] 
ElonN 1 758 308 M S U S1
ElonN 1 1110 700 M S U S1
ElonN 1 1887 2794 M S U S1
ElonN 1 4849 1190 M S U S1
;; cluster S10 [ score:FS = -34.466969784129404 ] [ score:FT = 
-34.951981832991414 ] [ score:MS = -34.83408030011385 ] [ score:MT = 
-35.17326803680231 ] 
ElonN 1 6731 352 F S U S10
;; cluster S11 [ score:FS = -33.57333115273301 ] [ score:FT = 
-33.93961876513661 ] [ score:MS = -32.6529742867516 ] [ score:MT = 
-33.397218081762475 ] 
ElonN 1 7459 2542 M S U S11
;; cluster S16 [ score:FS = -33.29482735979043 ] [ score:FT = 
-33.687616298740195 ] [ score:MS = -32.189984103971135 ] [ score:MT = 
-33.13899965310298 ] 
ElonN 1 10001 3051 M S U S16
ElonN 1 13086 912 M S U S16
;; cluster S9 [ score:FS = -33.4457701986847 ] [ score:FT = 
-34.70059869569136 ] [ score:MS = -33.958162156208914 ] [ score:MT = 
-34.79598011488008 ] 
ElonN 1 6039 692 F S U S9
```

**I have to extract the starting time(3rd column), duration of the speaking time(4th column) and the last column(speaker name).**

In the below segment

```
ElonN 1 6039 692 F S U S9
```

6039 is the starting time of the segment.
692 is the duration of the segment.
S9 is the speaker name.

The following shell script I wrote extracts the whole segment and stores in a file.

```
echo "Enter audio file name. (File must be of .wav format)"

read fileName

echo "Enter path of the audio file"

read path

echo "Enter folder name"

read outputfolder 

mkdir -p $outputfolder

echo "Processing $fileName"
./ilp_diarization2.sh $path/$fileName.wav 120 $outputfolder


grep "$fileName.*S" $outputfolder/$fileName/$fileName.g.3.seg > a


cat a
```

Comment: So what do you want want with exactly?

Comment: Extract the starting time(3rd column), duration of the speaking time(4th column) and the last column(speaker name) in a variable or a file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use wak and so:

```
var=$(awk '{ print $3" "$4" "$NF }' filename)
```

or

```
awk '{ print $3" "$4" "$NF }' filename > outputfile
```

$number refers to the space delimited (awk's default) piece of data you are concerned with.

Comment: What does $NF do here?

Comment: NF refers to the number of space separated field on each line. $NF therefore represents the contents of the last field.